# Django - Oracle, How to connect to readonly db with user/pass provided for the User

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-oracle

I need to connect Django with a read-only Oracle database.

The user and password to connect to that db is going to be provided by the User in a web form.

Any hint to do that?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: You could use cx_Oracle module

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-hints

Comment: @dalonlobo could you give me an example please? thanks

Comment: @TheHumbleGuy thanks for the link, but in those cases the databases connections, user, pass are defined in the settings.py. I need some way to set the user and pass on the fly.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, which will be easier to read

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code snippet that you can try out:

```
import cx_Oracle

con = cx_Oracle.connect('pythonhol/welcome@127.0.0.1/orcl')

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from departments order by department_id')
for result in cur:
    print result

cur.close()
con.close()
```

Word of caution, don't forget to close the connection, you can also use python context manager if you like. [Further Read](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html).